# sqlite3: near "." : syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables already created:

```
create table movies(id integer, name text, score integer);
create table cast(movie_id integer, cast_id integer, cast_name text);
```

I need the first 10 (distinct, alphabetically by cast_name) cast members and their average movie scores, so I tried:

```
select movie_id,cast_id,cast_name,id,score from cast,movies 
where movies.id=cast.movie_id and cast_name in 
(select distinct cast_name from cast order by cast_name limit 10);
```

But then I got an error message: near "." : syntax error

After that, I tried to make it simpler:

```
select cast_name, score from cast,movies where movies.id=cast.movie_id;
```

I still got the same error.

I guess this might be because '.' is a special command in sqlite3, but cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cast` is a reserved word.  The list of reserved words is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

```
select cast_name, score
from `cast` c join
     movies m
     on m.id = c.movie_id;
```

You can escape it using backticks or double quotes.  This query uses table aliases to simplify the query and more modern syntax for the join.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a column using . notation just call the columns by their name not the tablename.columnname